# create dynamic elements custom

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a custom `ImageView` and work if i add my element in my activity.xml, but dont work if i  try create dynamic element.

EDIT:**SOLVED**

[Here the repo](https://github.com/David-Hackro/Bounce-Animation)

*Note: dont execute the method onDraw*

**Activity class**

```
val xpp = resources.getXml(R.xml. octocat)

        val attr = Xml.asAttributeSet(xpp)



        val octocat :  OctocatView = OctocatView(this,attr)
        octocat.invalidate()
        val layout : LinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.layout)

        layout.addView(octocat)
```

** Java Class**

```
public class OctocatView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView{

    private Context mContext;

    public OctocatView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, Context mContext) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        this.mContext = mContext;

    }

    public OctocatView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)  {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
    }

    public OctocatView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;

    }


    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
       //some code
    }

}
```

Element XML `res/xml/octocat.xml`

```
<hackro.tutorials.com.salesfacebook.widget.OctocatView android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Comment: put the code when you create the view dynamically

Comment: sorry, i add the code

Comment: What is some code ? Put your code of onDraw here if you really want a answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the size of your `View` programmatically before adding it to the `LinearLayout`:

```
octocat.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

 layout.addView(octocat)
```